# Manage specific cookies in Browser?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, browser

I would like to manage cookies in the Android browser beyond just "Clear cookie data".

What I want to do, ideally, is have the ability to delete individual cookies from a list sorted by domain name, like Firefox on the desktop.

At least, I would like to be able to clear cookies per-domain, as I can manage storage & location access per-domain.

Is there a way I can do this?

**EDIT**

How about with a rooted phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookies, for the default android browser, are stored in /data/data/com.android.browser/databases/webview.db. The problem is that other applications, for security reasons, do not have access to files that do not belong to them, like the database file.

In order for what you are asking to be possible, the Browser application would have to implement this functionality.

Comment: I just rooted my phone two days ago. Does that change the situation at all? ;-)

Comment: You mean, like using the [SQLite Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.sqleditor) included with [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer)? Where you can edit the databases directly, if your device is rooted? No xD